# How to combine Index and Search for Text string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The problem:

I have a Database with 2 values, but I don't know how to setup the code for searching of key letters.

[Database, 2 values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZBlA.jpg)

[image]

It works fine if I search for the exact article Number, but I need a "dummy" search where I can search only for part of the text and not to brake my index formula.

[Searchfield and results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iFCR.jpg)

[image]

Code for the cells:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('Za Database'!$A$1:$D$10000;SMALL(IF('Za Database'!$A$1:$A$10000=$A$2;ROW('Za Database'!$A$1:$A$10000));ROW('Za Database'!1:1));4));"";INDEX('Za Database'!$A$1:$D$10000;SMALL(IF('Za Database'!$A$1:$A$10000=$A$2;ROW('Za Database'!$A$1:$A$10000));ROW('Za Database'!1:1));4))
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance

Comment: Partial means what? Like you want to search that has 12?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this formula. I don't know will it help you? It will search in column A which have 12 and return result from Column B.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$10,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2, $A$1:$A$10)),ROW($A$1:$A$10)),ROWS($A$1:$A1)),2),"")
```

[image]

Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter after entering formula as it is a array formula.

Comment: Hello, 

i need to be able to search for "groups" like lets say: "961*" or "*102". It's a huge database with more then 50k entries and if i type in the search field: "961*" it should give me all IDs where the article number starts with "961".

Comment: Yes It will do so. Do you try by replacing 12 (In formula) by $D$2 (Then put 961 or 102 in D2 cell? Or you only wants that starts with 961 (and so ....).

Comment: You should add a note that this is an Array Formula, which needs to be entered with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, instead of just ENTER. An explanation of how the formula works would also be valuable.

Comment: Oh! sorry I forgot that. I updated my formula and note also.

Comment: Thank you, this formula looks promising and seems to work. May i just ask one more question, i have article numbers like 961 13 and 961 135. How can i modify this formula so if i type 961 13 it just shows this one, not every item where that starts with 961 13?

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: So, you want exact match? Then your formula will like this `=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$11=$D$2,ROW($A$2:$A$11)),ROWS($A$2:$A2))),""‌​)`
Can you please send a mail to harun24hr@gmail.com so that I can send you a sample file which will show you, left, any, right, exact match filtering.